# Ruby on Rails noob named_scope with datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a .net developer that was handed a ruby on rails application because I took one class 5 years ago.  I am really a novice at understanding this application but I think I have found my problem now I need help to figure out how to fix it.

I have a schedule that shows audits and the time slots those audits are scheduled in.

in the schedules_controller.rb

```
@audits = Audit.after(Date.yesterday).before(Date.tomorrow).not_canceled.find_all_by_user_id(params[:id])
```

in the audit.rb model I have 2 named scopes

```
named_scope :after, lambda {|date| {:conditions => "date_time > '#{date} 23:59:00.000'"}}

named_scope: before, lambda {|date| {:conditions => "date_time < '#{date} 00:00:00.000'"}}
```

The datetimes in the database are stored in utc time so, when all the audits for today are shown the ones for later in the day are missing.  For example (when in EST) if I have an audit for 7:30pm today, it is stored in the database with tomorrows date because of the 5 hour difference.  Any suggestions on how to correct this issue? The application is in rails 2.3.5.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the time object into the scope instead of date so that it will be more accurate. You have to be conscious about time zones while doing so:

```
Time.zone = "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
start_time = Time.zone.parse("#{Date.today} 23:59:00")
end_time = Time.zone.parse("#{Date.yesterday} 00:00:00")
@audits = Audit.after(start_time)).before(end_time).not_canceled.find_all_by_user_id(params[:id])
```

and the scopes should be changed like this

```
named_scope :after, lambda {|time| {:conditions => ["date_time > ?", time]}}
named_scope :before, lambda {|time| {:conditions => ["date_time < ?", time]}}
```

The key here is the code `Time.zone.parse` which will parse the time assuming the string given is in the time zone specified by the line above. If we use `Time.parse` directly instead it will assumethe server machine clock's timezone as the timezone.

Here, `Date.today` is also risky as it gives date in server machine's timezone. There are two helper methods added by Rails to the time object as `beginning_of_day` and `end_of_day` which will give the correct time. So, using them, we can calculate

```
start_time = Time.zone.now.end_of_day - 1.day
end_time = Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day + 1.day
```

If in the `config/environment.rb`, you have already defined,

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

or the required time zone, you dont have to do the first line in the code (`Time.zone = "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"`). For getting the time zones in US, you can use `rake time:zones:us`. (For all timezones, it is `rake time:zones:all`)